# use samsung account as login for android application

Tags: android, authentication

I would like to know whether there is any API available for login using samsung account.
There are options for following:
1)Login using facebook account
2)Login using google account

But I would like to know about the samsung account.I have come to a link which is a year old on this.
 http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=244247

Can anyone give me a right direction for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There'is a open beta Samsung Account API, but you need to do a Partnership Request.

http://developer.samsung.com/account